# Upload lossless m4a to Sony walkman without conversion using Windows 10?

Tags: audio-conversion, m4a

Windows 10 Pro, Sony Walkman NWZ-W273S, 4GB, v. 1.0

Uploading (256kbit)m4a 109mb without conversion and it doesn't play, on the other hand if I convert it, along with the upload, the size gets reduced with 20mbs.

Is there a way to upload the file without any conversion and still make it work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Sony](http://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/walkman/nwz-w273-nwz-w274s/specifications), that machine can only use [AAC-LC DRM-Free format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding).

As you haven't given us the full encoding information of the file you are trying to play, the only assumption we can make is that is isn't that format & must be converted in order that the machine can play it.

File info after comments…

```
Information for File: 1hr Beta Binaural Beat Session (20hz) ~ Pure (256kbit).m4a

General / Container Stream # 1
    Total Audio Streams for this File -> 1
    Audio Codecs Used -> AAC LC
    File Format -> MPEG-4
    Play Time -> 1h 0mn
    Total File Size -> 109 MiB
    Total Stream BitRate -> 255 Kbps
    Encoded with -> Lavf56.4.101
Audio Stream # 1
    Codec -> AAC
    Codec (FourCC) -> 40
    Audio Stream Length -> 1h 0mn 0s 45ms
    Audio Stream BitRate -> 254 Kbps
    Audio Stream BitRate Mode -> CBR
    Number of Audio Channels -> 2
    Audio Channel's Positions -> L R
    Sampling Rate -> 44.1 KHz
    Bit Depth -> 16 bits
    Audio Stream Size -> 109 MiB (99%)
```

Which only leaves me with…
You'll have to ask Sony why it can't play that, as all indications are that it ought to be able to

Comment: where can I find the full encoding info of the file?

Comment: Anyway if that can help, I downloaded this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEHVz5XCmBs with JDownloader 2

Comment: I added the file info to the answer, but it leaves me no wiser, sorry.

Comment: So far I tried with the 'drag and drop' way of uploading also with the Windows Media Player sync option. Maybe there is some other program that can possibly make it work, I will keep experimenting and will share my insights.

Comment: So Media Go did the job for me but I am not sure if this is worth for an answer or it is just with me.